# symfony crud simple request

Tags: symfony, request, crud

i'm trying to do a simple add without the form generated by doctrine

```
$mail = new Subscription();
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->getMethod() == "POST") {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $samplees = $request->get("samplees");

    $mail->setEmail($samplees);

    $em->persist($mail);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_homepage'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Doctrine2 will not handle any form facility (nor creation neither data binding process): the whole process is up to symfony and its form bundle.

That said, if you need to retrieve a posted data you need to modify

```
$samplees = $request->get("samplees");
```

into

```
$samplees = $request->request->get("samplees");
```

This because `$request` is the *whole* Request object (so, basically, it will handle also get parameters [`$request->query->get(...)`] just to say one of the functionalities)

Comment: yeah thanks that's what i did and it worked except i figured that it will run an exception when i write the same mail twice because it's the primary key of the Subscription class